# Stitching MapProxy tiles to receive one georeferenced image

Tags: wms, image-mosaic, mapproxy

In my struggle to get a decent aerial image for playing around with as a layer in Biosphere3D (and for other purposes as well), I managed to install Mapproxy and then cached the area in my desired zoom level from a 2m-Orthophoto WMS through the proxy within QGIS.

Now I am in possession of tiles worth 60MB, but I see no way how to stitch them together to one image.

The tiles are stored in a folder-structure like this:
[image]

The following sets of tiles are in 32/000/781/000/25, 32/000/781/000/25 etc. containing 408.png to 431.png

I have no clue how to interpret this structure.

I wonder if there is any way (script) to stitch those tiles to receive one georeferenced image.

The tiles were captured in WGS84.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default MapProxy uses a TileCache compatible directory layout (zz/xxx/xxx/xxx/yyy/yyy/yyy.format), but you can use `directory_layout` for switch to TMS compatible directories (zz/xxxx/yyyy.format).

I've wrote little python script for stitching tiles from TileCache compatible directories into one big image. PIL library should be installed:

```
import os
import Image

z_level = 0
x_level = 3
y_level = 6
tile_size = 256

# Example of tile path: /home/denis/tilecache2tms/mymapproxy/cache_data/osm_cache_EPSG900913/05/000/000/023/000/000/016.png

base = "/home/denis/tilecache2tms/mymapproxy/cache_data/osm_cache_EPSG900913/"
path = "05"
tiles_paths = []

merged_path = os.path.join(base, path, 'merged.png') 
if os.path.isfile(merged_path):
    os.remove(merged_path)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(base, path)):
    for f in files:
        fname = f.split('.')[0]
        tiles_paths.append(os.path.join(root, fname).split('/')[-7:])

x_num_tiles = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(base, "/".join(tiles_paths[0][:x_level]))))
y_num_tiles = max([len(os.listdir(os.path.join(base, "/".join(tiles_paths[i][:y_level])))) for i in range(len(tiles_paths))])

width = tile_size*x_num_tiles
height = tile_size*y_num_tiles

print "Image size: %s x %s" % (str(width), str(height))

max_x_tile = max([int(d) for d in os.listdir(os.path.join(base, "/".join(tiles_paths[0][:x_level])))])
max_y_tile = max([int(tiles_paths[i][y_level]) for i in range(len(tiles_paths))])

print "Xmax: %s, Ymax: %s" % (str(max_x_tile), str(max_y_tile))

img = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))

for tile in tiles_paths:
    x_tile = int("".join(tile[1:x_level+1]))
    y_tile = int("".join(tile[4:y_level+1]))
    tile_img = Image.open("%s.%s" % (os.path.join(base, "/".join(tile)), 'png'))
    img.paste(tile_img, (width - (max_x_tile-x_tile+1)*tile_size, (max_y_tile-y_tile)*tile_size))

img.save(merged_path)

print "Image saved into: %s" % merged_path
```

Now you can use any appropriate software for georeferencing your image by coordinates.

---

For checking PIL works correctly try to create an empty image using PIL and paste not transparent tile into it (use your own paths):

```
import Image
img = Image.new('RGBA', (256, 256))
tile = Image.open('/home/denis/tilecache2tms/mymapproxy/cache_data/osm_cache_EPSG900913/06/000/000/042/000/000/035.png')
img.paste(tile, (0,0))
img.save('/home/denis/test.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Windows, the taho.exe tool might be helpful for you:

http://www.dimitri-junker.de/eng/html/openstreetmap.html

Although written to receive online tiles, it can be easily configured to use locally available tiles from `file:///` or localhost

The output can be set to larger tiles, or one complete image.

For Linux, you would have to extend the taho.pl by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I made a small bugfix to your code for y positions of tiles:

```
import os
# import Image from Pillow
from PIL import Image

z_level = 0
x_level = 3
y_level = 6
tile_size = 256

# Example of tile path: /home/denis/tilecache2tms/mymapproxy/cache_data/osm_cache_EPSG900913/05/000/000/023/000/000/016.png

base = "/home/denis/tilecache2tms/mymapproxy/cache_data/osm_cache_EPSG900913/"

path = "05"    
tiles_paths = []

merged_path = os.path.join(base, path, 'merged.png')
if os.path.isfile(merged_path):
    os.remove(merged_path)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(base, path)):
    for f in files:
        fname = f.split('.')[0]
        tiles_paths.append(os.path.join(root, fname).split('/')[-7:])

x_num_tiles = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(base, "/".join(tiles_paths[0][:x_level]))))
y_num_tiles = max([len(os.listdir(os.path.join(base, "/".join(tiles_paths[i][:y_level])))) for i in range(len(tiles_paths))])

width = tile_size*x_num_tiles
height = tile_size*y_num_tiles

print("Image tiles: %s x %s" % (str(x_num_tiles), str(y_num_tiles)))

print("Image size: %s x %s" % (str(width), str(height)))

min_x_tile = min([int(d) for d in os.listdir(os.path.join(base, "/".join(tiles_paths[0][:x_level])))])
min_y_tile = min([int(tiles_paths[i][y_level]) for i in range(len(tiles_paths))])

print("Xmin: %s, Ymin: %s" % (str(min_x_tile), str(min_y_tile)))

max_x_tile = max([int(d) for d in os.listdir(os.path.join(base, "/".join(tiles_paths[0][:x_level])))])
max_y_tile = max([int(tiles_paths[i][y_level]) for i in range(len(tiles_paths))])

print("Xmax: %s, Ymax: %s" % (str(max_x_tile), str(max_y_tile)))

img = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))

for tile in tiles_paths:
    x_tile = int("".join(tile[1:x_level+1]))
    y_tile = int("".join(tile[4:y_level+1]))

    tile_img = Image.open("%s.%s" % (os.path.join(base, "/".join(tile)), 'png'))

    x_tile_position = width - (max_x_tile-x_tile+1)*tile_size
    y_tile_position = height - (max_y_tile-y_tile)*tile_size

    print('assemble tile:',x_tile,',',y_tile,'->',x_tile_position,',',y_tile_position)

    img.paste(tile_img, (x_tile_position, y_tile_position))

img.save(merged_path)

print("Image saved into: %s" % merged_path)
```